# How to store media DRM keys for offline usage in Android

Tags: offline, drm, exoplayer2.x

Wanted to check is there any API provided by Android which can be used to store DRM keys securely.

We are using OfflineLicenseHelper to download DRM keys for offline usage of drm media asset. But we are concerned on how to store the keys securely.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a standard DRM solution, mostly likely Widevine if it is on Android, then you don't need to worry about storing the keys securely yourself as this is part of the functionality that the DRM system provides.

The DRM system will securely store the keys and provide them to the secure media path in the device when you request playback.

Comment: Thanks @Mick. Can you please elaborate which apis stores the keys securely. We are using OfflineLicenseHelper class to download the license.

Comment: The DRM license contains the content encryption key and rules associated with it including the time it is valid for. All this is encrypted in the DRM license at the server side and passed to the DRM system on your client which stores it and which should be the only entity on your client able to decrypt the license. So in other words the storage is happening as part of the DRM system itself.